Calculate the rank of a matrix expression
I'm studying discrete-time LTI systems and state estimators for them. Recently, I studied this paper. I am facing a matrix rank calculation problem and having trouble solving it. I will provide more details below and would appreciate any help.
Consider the discrete-time LTI system with the following state-space representation:
\begin{align}
    {x}_{k+1}&={A} {x}_k+{B} {u}_k  &;{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, {B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \\ 
    {y}_k&={C} {x}_k  &;{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n} 
\end{align}
where $ {x}_k \in \mathbb{R}^n $ is the state, $ {u}_k \in \mathbb{R}^m $ is the control input and $ {y}_k \in \mathbb{R}^p $ is the measured output.
Suppose, this system is controllable and observable, also assume that $\mathrm{N}=\mathrm{n}$. So the controllability matrix $B_N$ and the observability matrix $O_N$, which are constructed as follows, are of rank $n$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& B_N=\left[\begin{array}{llll}
A^{N-1} B & \cdots & A B & B
\end{array}\right] \\
& O_N=\left[\begin{array}{c}
C \\
C A \\
\vdots \\
C A^{N-1}
\end{array}\right] \\
\end{aligned}
$$
I want to find the rank of matrix $M$, which is defined as below. The M matrix appears when we want to write the state of the system at any time based on the previous inputs and outputs of the system.
\begin{equation}
     x_k=M\begin{bmatrix}
                     u_N(k-N) \\
                     y_N(k-N) 
                   \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
  u_N(k-N)={\begin{bmatrix}
             u_{k-N}^T & u_{k-N+1}^T & \cdots & u_{k-1}^T 
           \end{bmatrix}}^T
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  y_N(k-N)={\begin{bmatrix}
             y_{k-N}^T & y_{k-N+1}^T & \cdots & y_{k-1}^T 
           \end{bmatrix}}^T
\end{equation*}
$$
\begin{aligned}
& T_N=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\
C B & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
C A B & C B & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
C A^{N-2} B & \cdots & \cdots & C B & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
& O_N^{+}=\left(O_N^T O_N\right)^{-1} O_N^T \\
& M=\left[B_N-A^N O_N^{+} T_N \quad A^N O_N^{+}\right] \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
Through simulation with different examples, I observe that the rank of matrix $M$ is $n$, and I am seeking either a proof of this statement or a counterexample.

Be very careful about any conclusions you make regarding rank via simulation: where multiple ranks are possible, typically the largest rank will be the most likely with practically 100% probability

A little bit of context as to where the matrix $M$ comes from might be useful

You are correct. I'm not sure about the rank of $M$. I need to calculate it.

That much about $M$ you've already explained. I'm asking, for instance, if there is any problem that knowing the rank of $M$ would solve or if there is some interpretation of $M$ in the context of control theory

If you are familiar with linear control and state space representation of discrete time LTI systems, The M matrix appears when we want to write the state of the system at any time based on the previous inputs and outputs of the system.

\begin{equation}
x_k=M\begin{bmatrix}
u_N(k-N) \
y_N(k-N)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
u_N(k-N)={\begin{bmatrix}
u_{k-N}^T & u_{k-N+1}^T & \cdots & u_{k-1}^T
\end{bmatrix}}^T
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
y_N(k-N)={\begin{bmatrix}
y_{k-N}^T & y_{k-N+1}^T & \cdots & y_{k-1}^T
\end{bmatrix}}^T
\end{equation*}

where $ {x}_k \in \mathbb{R}^n $ is the state, $ {u}_k \in \mathbb{R}^m $ is the control input and $ {y}_k \in \mathbb{R}^p $ is the measured output.

Thank you; that's exactly what I was looking for

In the case that $A$ is invertible, we can see that $M$ must have full rank as follows: note that $O_N^+O_N = I_n$, so that
$$
M = A^{N}O_N^+ \begin{bmatrix}
O_NA^{-N}B_N - T_N & I_{p \cdot N}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Because the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
O_NA^{-N}B_N - T_N & I_{p \cdot N}
\end{bmatrix}$ has full row rank, the rank of $M$ is equal to that of $A^N O_N^+$, which is necessarily equal to $n$.

\begin{equation}
M=A^N O_{N}^+ \begin{bmatrix}
O_{N} A^{-N} B_{N}-T_{N} & I_{p.N}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Thanks Ben, it was a great idea. I also need to prove it for noninvertible A.

@apa I fixed the typo. Also, I haven't been able to think of a suitable approach for the non-invertible case, unfortunately

Does anyone have any ideas for the case $m=p=1$? With this assumption, the matrix $O_N$ is a square invertible matrix. We want to show that the rank of $\begin{bmatrix} B_N-A^n O_N^{-1}T_N  & A^nO_N^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$ is equal to $n$. Also, remember that $N=n$.

@apa In the case that $m = 1$, the matrix $B_N^{-1}AB_N$ is a companion matrix; perhaps this is a helpful observation. Also, I wonder if there is an indirect proof that one could arrive at with the help of systems theory. In particular, it appears to me that $M$ failing to have full rank necessarily means that the system cannot be controllable since there would be elements $x$ of the state space that lie outside the column space of $M$ and thus cannot be attained.

From the expression for $ M $, where $ M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (m+p)n} $, it follows that:
\begin{equation}\label{eq.M_rank}
  M \begin{bmatrix}
      I_{mn} \\
      T_n
    \end{bmatrix}
    =\begin{bmatrix}
         B_n-A^n O_n^{+} T_n & A^n O_n^{+} 
       \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      I_{mn} \\
      T_n
    \end{bmatrix}=B_n
\end{equation}
Since the system is controllable,  $rank(B_n)=n$. By applying Sylvester's rank inequality, it is established that  $rank(M)\geq n$. Given the dimensions of $ M $, it also holds that $rank(M)\leq n$. Therefore, it follows that $rank(M)=n$, confirming that $ M $ has full row rank.
